# Error scheduling jobs using Spring annotations

Tags: spring, maven, maven-2, maven-3, spring-batch

I am trying to schedule jobs using annotations Spring.. My configuration file is as follows:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans       
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-   
   util.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-
   task-3.0.xsd">

   <task:annotation-driven />
   <util:properties id="batchProp" location="application.properties" />
   <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="batchProp" />
   <bean id="indexer" class="package-name"></bean>
   </beans>
```

and this is how I am invoking it:

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
    ApplicationContext appCont = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Config.xml");
    prop_file = appCont.getBean("batchProp", Properties.class);
  }
```

My pom build segment is file:

```
  <build>
     <plugins>
    <plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
           <archive>
                          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <mainClass>my_main_class</mainClass> 
              </manifest>
           </archive>
               <descriptorRefs>
                          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                   </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
               <id>make-my-jar-with-dependencies</id>
               <phase>package</phase> 
               <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
               </goals>
                </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

this works abosultely fine when I run it in Spring Tool Suite but throws an error when I run the jar file in the server.
The error is as follows:

```
  Exception in thread "main"    
  org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration   problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/task]
  Offending resource: class path resource [Spring-Config.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:316)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:527)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:441)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.mypackage.name.Indexer.main(Indexer.java:204)
```

Can someone please tell me what's going on?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are no spring jar with "task" namespace (and maybe not only "task", but all namespaces: try to put "task:annotation-driven" after "util:properties" and you see other message) definition at servers classpath.
Check that server doesnt have old spring jars in its "libs" directory.
Try to put necessary spring jars to servers "libs" directory.